# Android : Playing audio file repeatedly on Push-Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-mediaplayer

I was wondering if there is a method to play an audio file on receiving a push notification. It's a **short tone** of **1second** which I want to play for about **1minute** at a **gap of 10seconds** each. Thus, playing the file 6 times in a minute.
This audio file is *locally stored in the APP* itself.

So, is there a way in which this can be done **without** running background services and when the app is closed?